# How to include a sorting method in program?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, lines

Here are the requirements for the program. Essentially the output must be as follows while still adhering to the guidelines below. My question is how do I alter my program to meet requirement #4 (which is writing a method that takes the student data in the 1-D and 2-D arrays and prints the student records: names, 2 quiz scores and the average. The output fields should be well-aligned.) My second question is how do I meet requirement #6 (A header line should be printed before the student records, and a line “-------------------“ should be printed every 2 students).

```
 # Name    Q1   Q2
```

---

1. name1        ... ... ...
2. name2 ... ... ...

---

3. name3 ... ... ...
4. name4 ... ... ...

---

5. name5 ... ... ...

==================================================================================
1. Inside the main() method, define a 1-D array that can store 5 student names. Define a 2-D array inside the main() that store the 5 students (rows) exam record that each student has 3 data fields (columns): 2 quiz scores and an average of the 2 quizzes.

2. Assign student names (real name) to 1-D array and 2 quiz scores to the 2-D array.
3. Calculate the average of 2 quizzes for each student.

**4. Write a method that takes the student data (1-D and 2-D arrays) and sort the student records from high to low by the average field.**

5. Write a method that takes the student data (1-D and 2-D arrays) and prints the student records: names, 2 quiz scores and the average. The output fields should be well-aligned.

**6. A header line should be printed before the student records, and a line “-------------------“ should be printed every 2 students.**

7. The following output is an example:

## Name   Q1  Q2 Avg

---

1. name1 ... ... ...
2. name2 ... ... ...

---

3. name3 ... ... ...
4. name4 ... ... ...

---

5. name5 ... ... ...

=================================================================================

**Here's what I have so far. Im really having trouble with the sorting method and a line “-------------------“ printed every 2 students.**

public class studentGrades {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create variables to be used inside the "for" loops as counters
    int i;
    int row;
    int column;

    String[] students = {"Peter", "Lydia", "Kate", "Steve", "Alexa"};



    // Create a 2-D array of the int type to stores scores
    int[][] scores = { {82, 90}, {78,90}, {84, 80}, {85, 73}, {81, 93} };


    // Display headings for information to be spaced equally
    System.out.printf("%-7s%-7s%-7s%-7s%-7s", "Name",
            "Test1", "Test2", "Sum of tests ", "Average grade\n");
    System.out.print("----------------------------------------\n");


    for (i = 0; i <students.length; i++){


        System.out.print(students[i] + " \n");


    }


    // cycle through the each group (outside part of the array)
        for (row=0; row<scores.length; row++){

            //create variables to store computations and set initial value to zero
            int sum = 0;
            double  avg = 0;
            //System.out.print(students[i]);


            // cycle through each set of elements of each group (inside part of array)
            for (column=0; column<scores[row].length; column++){


                // for each set of elements -- add all elements in each group (int sum must be set to 0 each time)
                     sum += scores[row][column];

                     // calculate average by dividing the value in int sum by the number of elements in the group (group size)
                     avg = sum/scores[column].length;



                     // display the values of each row
                 System.out.print(scores[row][column] + "      ");


            }



        // display the sum of each group (row) with an identifying message
            System.out.print(sum + "           " );


            // display the average of each group (row) with an identifying message
           System.out.print(avg);

        //    System.out.print(" -------------------------\n");
           // create new line after each computation
            System.out.println();

            // Create dotted lines to separate each set of values displayed
            System.out.print("----------------------------------------\n");

    }
    ///////
```

}
}

Comment: Please indent and format the question clearly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
package Examples;

public class MarksQuiz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create variables to be used inside the "for" loops as counters
        int i;
        int row;
        int column;
        String[] students = { "Peter", "Lydia", "Kate", "Steve", "Alexa" };
        // Create a 2-D array of the int type to stores scores
        int[][] scores = { { 82, 90 }, { 78, 90 }, { 84, 80 }, { 85, 73 }, { 81, 93 } };

        // Display headings for information to be spaced equally
        System.out.printf("%-7s%-7s%-7s%-7s%-7s", "Name", "Test1", "Test2", "Sum of tests ", "Average grade\n");
        System.out.print("----------------------------------------\n");

        //Removed the For loop from Here
        /*for (i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(students[i] + " \n");
        }*/

        // cycle through the each group (outside part of the array)
        for (row = 0; row < scores.length; row++) {

                System.out.print(students[row]);//Inserted the Print Statement to Fix your Issue
                    // create variables to store computations and set initial value to
            // zero
            int sum = 0;
            double avg = 0;
            // System.out.print(students[i]);

            // cycle through each set of elements of each group (inside part of
            // array)
            for (column = 0; column < scores[row].length; column++) {

                // for each set of elements -- add all elements in each group
                // (int sum must be set to 0 each time)
                sum += scores[row][column];

                // calculate average by dividing the value in int sum by the
                // number of elements in the group (group size)
                avg = sum / scores[column].length;

                // display the values of each row
                System.out.print(scores[row][column] + "      ");

            }

            // display the sum of each group (row) with an identifying message
            System.out.print(sum + "           ");

            // display the average of each group (row) with an identifying
            // message
            System.out.print(avg);

            // System.out.print(" -------------------------\n");
            // create new line after each computation
            System.out.println();

            // Create dotted lines to separate each set of values displayed
            System.out.print("----------------------------------------\n");

        }
    }
}
```

Output:-

### Name   Test1  Test2  Sum of tests Average grade

### Peter82      90      172           86.0

### Lydia78      90      168           84.0

### Kate84      80      164           82.0

### Steve85      73      158           79.0

### Alexa81      93      174           87.0

Comment: I think output is expected to be sorted by Average column

Comment: Please do not do homework assignments for other people.  That is not the purpose of StackOverflow.